# Code Coverage 83% in production 75% in sandbox - can't deploy

Tags: apex, code-coverage, failing-tests

In production, code coverage is showing 83%.  In sandbox, it is showing 75%.  I have just 1 apex class and associated test class I am trying to deploy to production, but it fails saying only 30% coverage.  The apex class I am trying to deploy has 90% coverage, why can't I deploy this class and associated test class to production?

Comment: What test run level did you choose when performing the deployment? Does your unit test class use `seeAllData=true`? What does the actual code look like?

Comment: I use the "Default" test level @DavidReed.   I am not using seeAllData=true.  I did notice that the test class does NOT have any assert statements, though the ape class shows 90% coverage.  Would this cause an issue?

Comment: Do you have any unmanaged package installed in the org? Do you 'see' the test coverage overall and for individual classes? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&type=5 (not undermining anyone's expertise - just putting it out there for future reference!)

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a trigger in my change set.  The trigger actually called the apex class, adding that fixed it.